# How to understanding the meaning of C++03 13.5.3/2

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct B {
    virtual int operator= (int rhs)
    {
        m_iValue = rhs;
        return m_iValue;
    }

    virtual B& operator= (const B& rhs)
    {
        m_iValue = rhs.m_iValue;
        return *this;
    }

    int m_iValue;
};
struct D : B {
    virtual int operator= (int rhs)
    {
        m_iValue = rhs;
        return m_iValue;
    }

    virtual D& operator= (const B& rhs)
    {
        m_iValue = rhs.m_iValue;
        return *this;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    D dobj1;
    D dobj2;
    B* bptr = &dobj1;

    bptr->operator=(99);     // calls D::operator=(int)
    *bptr = 99;              // ditto
    bptr->operator=(dobj2);  // calls D::operator=(const B&)
    *bptr = dobj2;           // ditto
    dobj1 = dobj2;           // calls implicitly-declared
                             // D::operator=(const D&)
    return 0;
}
```

**Question 1**> This question maybe is related to the question 2&3.

Reference: C++03 13.5.3/2

> Note: for a derived class D with a base class B for which a virtual
>   copy assignment has been declared, the copy assignment operator in D
>   does not override B’s virtual copy assignment operator.

What does the following statement mean in plain English?

> the copy assignment operator in D does not override B’s virtual copy
>   assignment operator.

**Question 2**>  why the following statement call `D::operator=(int)

```
    *bptr = 99;              // ditto
```

**Question 3**> Why the following statement call implicit `D::operator=(const D&)`

```
    dobj1 = dobj2;           // calls implicitly D::operator=(const D&)
```

Comment: For Q2&3 you should perhaps explain what you expected to happen and why.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1.
For `B`, the copy assignment operator  is `B::operator=(const B&)` or similar.  For `D` it's `D::operator=(const D&)`. One cannot override the other because argument types are different.

Comment: Except... for D it's `D::operator=(const B&)` so the argument types are identical. The return types differ, however.

Comment: Copy assignment operator, by definition, takes the argument of the same type as the left-hand side. So your `operator=` is not a copy assignment. Just an assignment.